# Convert 00 to 12 in JS

Tags: javascript, time

I have this code that allows me to go from 12 hour to 24 hour time in js and vice versa. Here it is:

```
setInterval( function() {
  var time = new Date();
  var twelveTime = time.toLocaleString('en-UK', { hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', second: '2-digit', hour12: true });
  var normalTime = time.toLocaleString('en-UK', { hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', second: '2-digit', hour12: false });
  if ($("#timeCheck").is(":checked")) $("#time").html(twelveTime);
  else $("#time").html(normalTime);
  /* Save 12 or 24 */
  setInterval(function saveTimeMode() {
    var checkbox = document.getElementById("timeCheck");
    localStorage.setItem("timeCheck", checkbox.checked);
  }, 0);
  var checked = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("timeCheck"));
  document.getElementById("timeCheck").checked = checked;
}, 50);
```

but the problem is that when it is in 12 hour time and is 12:00 PM, then it shows it as 00:00. How do I change this. Also it has to be in LocalString as my code would not work otherwise. Thanks

Comment: `en-UK` is probably not valid and should probably be `en-GB` - don't think it will make a difference though!

Comment: So *every* millisecond you write the checkbox state to local storage??

Comment: Whoa whoa whoa... are you calling `setInterval(..., 0)` *inside* a `setInterval(..., 50)`????? STOP! If you want to save the state of a checkbox in `localStorage`, just set it on `change` events!

Comment: Anyway, looks like the UK locale uses `00 AM` and `00 PM` to mean midnight and noon respectively. If you want `12 AM` for midnight and `12 PM` noon (which, frankly, makes absolutely no sense at all to me...) then use `'en-US'` since they do all the weird date stuff like that.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol What do you mean by set it in a `change` events? No other option worked for me? Thanks

Comment: `document.getElementById('timeCheck').addEventListener('change', function() {localStorage.timeCheck = this.checked;});`. This should be done OUTSIDE of any `setInterval`. You should probably also move the `var checked = ...` part of your code outside the loop too.

Comment: Thanks! It made it much smoother and simpler

Comment: BAD CODE ! you have a `setInterval` (of zero ms) created each 50ms by an otther  `setInterval`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had to change it from en_US from en_UK. Thanks!